# Oscillator circuit operation confusion

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-theory

In this circuit and explanation, it all makes sense except I'm having a hard time picturing Q2 not turning on until C1 has discharged first.

When C1 is discharging through Q1 why doesn't Q2 turn on as it's discharging since it's base is higher than 0.6v through R2?

Also is C1 discharging only by the + plate having a path to ground rather than both + and - plates of C1 being connected together?[image: 1][image: 2]

Comment: Draw the waveforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose C1 is charged with 4 Volts with the positive voltage at side marked +.

Now suppose that Q1 switches on pulling the collector of Q1 to 0 V (ground). Since C1 is still charged with 4 V, the base of Q2 will be at - 4 V. So Q2 is forced to be off as Vbe < 0.6 V. It is actually negative !

The base of Q2 needs to be above 0.6 V before it can conduct so C1 has to discharge to at least -0.6 V for that to happen (still assuming Q1 to be on so C1's + plate is 0 V).

So in reality C1 first discharges completely (to 0 Volt) and then charges with **opposite polarity** to at least 0.6 V.

For discharging a capacitor it is not really needed to short the capacitor plates. As long as the voltage on both plates is **the same** then the capacitor is discharged. It does not matter how this is achieved (making the voltages the same).

Comment: Thank you. If you could help me wrap my head around why the base of Q2 sees -4v when C1 is still charged? Why is the voltage there negative if R2 connects the base directly to Vcc? Is it because when Q1 is on it's actually pulling Vcc down as well?

Comment: C1 capacitor previously charged to 4V. The voltage polarity across the capacitor is: left plate of C1 is at + and the right plate is at "-". So when Q1 turns on he connected the left plate of a C1 capacitor to gnd, so the right plate becomes -4V and this is why we have a negative voltage at the Q2 base.

Comment: What G36 writes. The Vcc is not pulled down, it is the voltage at the collector of Q1 which is pulled down. When C1 is charged you can see it as a 4 V battery with the + at the collector of Q1. Then Q1 closes, collector becomes 0 V so the - side of "battery" C1 becomes - 4 V.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh so a capacitor can have a negative charge as well on the negative plate? Even electrolytics?

Comment: You mean that it can have a negative charge on the positive plate. Yes **any** capacitor can be charged either way. However on **polarized** capacitors (for example electrolytic caps) there is a limit on the reverse voltage. Here that will be less than 1 V. Normal electrolytic caps do not have a problem with that. You **can** charge a 25 V rated electrolytic cap to -25 V but it will not like that, it will start getting warm and eventually it will blow off pressure or even blow itself up. After that it must be replaced.

Comment: The negative voltage means that the voltage at the capacitor right plate is 4V lower than the left plate. Because now the left plate is at 0 potential (when Q1 is ON). http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/3451835100_1502723952.png

Comment: @G36 Is that because the right plate develops a negative charge?

Comment: @user140123 do the battery negative terminal " develops a negative charge"? Replace the C1 capacitor with a 4V battery. And connect the positive battery terminal to the Q1 collector. And answer yourself a question. What is the voltage at the Q2 base (when Q1 is in saturation, full on)?

Comment: It would be 0v right? @G36

Comment: No wrong, why 0V?

Comment: I'm getting confused somehow. I keep thinking C1 is connected to Vcc+ and ground. So if the left plate goes to ground the right plate charges but since it's the - plate it becomes -4v charged by vcc?

Comment: The capacitor voltages cannot instantaneously change. The C1 capacitor was previously charged to 4V. And now when Q1 turn on and "shorts" C1 left plate to ground the situation looks like this http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/6939870100_1502730909.png

Comment: I replace C1 capacitor with 4V voltage source because the capacitor voltage cannot change immediately.  The voltage at point B (Q2 base) with respect to ground is now -4V. And the C1 capacitor stars the discharge phase. And voltage at point B gradually increasing his voltage thank to R2 and Vcc. As times goes on the voltage at C1 "drops" ( from -4V to 0V)

Comment: and when the C1 voltage reaches 0V the capacitor starts the charging process but in the opposite direction this time. And finally when C1 voltage reach 0.6V Q2 turn ON and this turns off Q1. Try read this https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/astable-multivibrator-how-does-it-work.32164/#post-200183

Comment: *I keep thinking C1 is connected to Vcc+ and ground* Well, is it ? No it is not. So why think that then ??? *So if the left plate goes to ground the right plate charges* **NO**, it does not charge. it takes a while to charge/discharge. At the moment the + plate is connected to ground, the - plate is **instantaneously** at -4 V. No charge flows **yet**. Immediately after this happens the cap starts discharging.

Comment: Ok but is the right plate -4v because it starts to charge from vcc in opposite polarity? My only confusion is figuring out why the right plate becomes -4v when the left is 0v

Comment: It is because the capacitor is charged to 4 V with + on left, - on right. Then connect left (+) side to 0 V (ground) potential, now what will be the voltage (with ground as reference, ground = 0 Volt) of the right (-) plate ? I think you're confused about voltage potential (referenced to ground) and voltage **across** a component like 4 V across the capacitor.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes you're right that's what's confusing me.  I think I'm mixing up the two